# Android Studio saying places api not enabled

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to use the Places API in my app. My Logcat keeps giving me these two errors even though the Api is enabled:

```
03-17 05:31:34.777 2759-3241/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/Volley: 
[158] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for 
https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/getAutocompletePredictions? 
key=<api key>

03-17 05:31:34.782 2759-7906/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/Places: 
Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See 
https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
```

I've tried adding

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

but neither seems to have helped. I'm able to search for a location, but as I type in the search bar, I get a "Places_Api_Access_Not_Configured" error. My Api dashboard shows that there is activity, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

This is what my dependencies currently look like

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.webjars.npm:debug:4.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.7.0'
    //implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Place Picker` or `Place Autocomplete` you should avoid them, because they are deprecated since January 29, 2019 as indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro).

An alternative for `Place Picker` is to implement it yourself, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449891/how-to-make-a-custom-place-picker-for-android) thread.
And if you want to use `Place Autocomplete` I suggest you give [Pelias](https://github.com/pelias/pelias/) a go.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes they are caching issues. **Try delete the API key and re-create it again**. Make sure you are not restricting the API key.

Only apply the restrictions after the key is working properly. Note, you might need to wait 5 minutes before using the new key.

When using the Google Places API for Web, you will also need to enable the Google Maps JavaScript API.

Comment: I have tried to uninstall my app from emulator and reinstall it with the newly generated KEY and it does not seem to work. But when I used an older KEY from another project it worked!, but I sill want to use this new KEY from this specific project. My places dependency is `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'`